# Автоматическая высота балуна

Tags: яндекс-карты

Подскажите, как сделать высоту двухколоночного балуна  автоматической в зависимости от контента?

Балун выводится в кластере через remoteObjectManager, задаю такие опции для регулирования размеров:

```js
options.clusterBalloonLeftColumnWidth = 200;
options.clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth = 650;
options.clusterBalloonContentLayoutHeight = 450;
```

Но это фиксированные значения, а мне надо, чтобы высота определялась автоматически по высоте контента.

Comment: Опции такой нет. Но можно написать свой балун: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сегодняшний день (последняя версия 2.1.68) такой возможности нет.